# Como hacer para que mi sistema apunte a Login en vez a la vista welcome

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap, login, rutas

Hola amigos una pregunta sencilla y rapida.. pero aunque sea facil no puedo encontrar una solucion razonable...
tengo un proyecto desarrolado con laravel 8, pero quiero que al entrar ala raiz...me muestre mi pagina del login... y no la pagina welcome que define por defecto al crear el proyecto... genere la autenticacion con bootstrap y en mi archivo web.php tengo lo siguiente:

Route::get('/',function(){return view('welcome');})

y quisiera que la ruta raiz apunte a login... nomas al ingresar al sistema. espero sus respuestas..

Comment: Recuerda que es importante agregar que has intentado, por favor lee [ask], además especificar si el login lo haces desde cero o con algún package

Answer (score 0):

prueba a poner `Route::get('/',function(){return view('auth.login');})` o la ruta a la vista que corresponda en vez de apuntar a la vista welcome. la estructura de carpertas en auth.login seria /views/auth/login.blade.php.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

por lo que dices has creado las rutas de autentificación y mencionas que para acceder al sistema debes pasar por el login, lo ideal es que hagas un MIDDLEWARE (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware) sigue la documentación si lo que haces es mostrar el inicio de sesión como la ruta principal (lo cual está bien) de todas maneras tu sistema quedará expuesto por la URL como HTTP GET.

No olvides guiarte por la documentación oficial de laravel, debes hacer un middleware para que cada vez que ingresen al sistema valide si el usuario está logeado, si es un invitado debes redireccionarlo al Iniciar sesión.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la ayuda y con respecto al problema... intente con
Route::get('/',function(){return view('auth.login');})
lo cual funciono, pero... habia un problemilla... si me autenticaba.. e ingresaba al sistemas por defecto me manda al home y si trataba de ingresar ala raiz , me mandaba nuevamente al login... aun estando autenticado... jajaja... lo cual no era correcto.
luego intente usar los middleware, pero como instale la autenticacion con bootstrap, ya me hizo instalo tambien los middleware, es decir, mi vista home ya tiene la restriccion de ser ingresado solo por usuarios autenticados, entonces... si pongo lo siguiente en el web.php:

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

por defecto me enviara al login, por que no estoy autenticado... pero si estoy autenticado.. me mandara al home.index... es decir no es necesario apuntar al login de manera explicita... si uso la logica del middleware... implicitamente me mandara al login... al querer entrar a cualquier direccion... no se si me deje entender...
pero me funciona asi...
saludos.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un sistema que ya hace eso, déjame te muestro
(Incluyo los controladores para  que veas como redireccionan por si acaso)

Este es el LoginController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
                        
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin/inicio';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showLoginForm(){
        return redirect('/');
    } 
}
```

Y este es el AdminController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {      
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

De esta manera manejo las rutas (este es un ejemplo de mi archivo web.php):

```
<?php

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Route::middleware('auth')->prefix('/admin')->group(function () {

Route::get('/inicio', 'AdminController@index');

    /* RUTA PRUEBA DE UN MODULO */
    Route::get('/pruebas', 'PruebaController@index')->name('pruebas.index');
    Route::get('/pruebas/create/', 'PruebaController@create')->name('pruebas.create');
    Route::post('/pruebas', 'PruebaController@store')->name('pruebas.store');
    Route::get('/pruebas/{prueba}/edit', 'PruebaController@edit')->name('pruebas.edit');
    Route::patch('/pruebas/{prueba}', 'PruebaController@update')->name('pruebas.update');
    Route::delete('/pruebas/{prueba}', 'PruebaController@destroy')->name('pruebas.destroy');
});
```